# Python/kivy - textinput to label

Tags: python, kivy

my question is about python and kivy. I am currently building an app with python and kivy however I got stuck in a very important step of this process. I need to transfer the textinput of one screen to be a label on another screen...I´ve already tried some tips but without success..I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: read [ask], review the [tour] and show that you have tried

Comment: Please show us what you tried. We can't be of much help if we don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

## Accessing Widgets defined inside Kv lang in your kv file

In the following example, we are using `ids` to reference TextInput widget in first screen from the second screen. Please refer to the snippet and example for details.

### Snippet

```
ScreenManager:
    FirstScreen:
        id: first_screen
    SecondScreen:
        id: second_screen


<FirstScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'firstScreen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TextInput:
            id: user_input
            text: 'testing-1-2-3'
...
<SecondScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'secondScreen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            # Accessing Widgets using ids
            text: root.manager.ids.first_screen.ids.user_input.text
```

[Kv language » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

> In a widget tree there is often a need to access/reference other
>   widgets. The Kv Language provides a way to do this using id’s

[ScreenManager » Basic Usage](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage)

> Each screen has by default a property `manager` that gives you the
>   instance of the ScreenManager used.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

ScreenManager:
    FirstScreen:
        id: first_screen
    SecondScreen:
        id: second_screen


<FirstScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'firstScreen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TextInput:
            id: user_input
            text: 'testing-1-2-3'

        Button:
            text: 'Second Screen'
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'secondScreen'


<SecondScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'secondScreen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            # Accessing Widgets using ids
            text: root.manager.ids.first_screen.ids.user_input.text

        Button:
            text: 'First Screen'
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'firstScreen'

'''))
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - TextInput in Screen1]
[image: Img02 - Label in Screen2]